# Write back to database with SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, sql-insert

Is there any way I can write back to the database in the report?
I know that I can use the parameters at the top to pass a value and insert the data into the database with sql.

I'd like to have an editable field in my report with an initial value and the possibility to save the changes to the database.

Any chance to do this with SSRS?
Maybe some kind of add-on?
If not, is there an free alternative reporting engine that can do the job?

I know Infor BI can be used for such tasks, but the licenses are expensive, especially if this is the only benefit.

Comment: it depends what you want to write back. a delete button i've done in the past, but a comment is not going to be easy. and if you need to write back much, it's a good indication that you're not doing a report anymore but an application..

Comment: You're absolutely right, we need some kind of application for our budgeting process.
We don't need to write much data, just some values for the cost centers.
I don't know which tool of the Microsoft stack would be suitable for our purpose.

Comment: easiest is an excel sheet, but automated. You generate forms with actual data and pre-filled budget columns, and you also have code to read back the budget values users have input. The other option is to use analysis services cubes with the write back function, but that's quite complicated and you need some tweaks to make it usable. if you go for a server based thing you'd be better off with palo or tm1-like olap cubes.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have an editable field on a report for any reason (doesn't exist).  Like others have alluded to, you can use parameters to insert values back into the database, or have a button image that reloads the page with a new hidden parameter value that then gets inserted into a database.

You will need a different application/technology to achieve what you are looking for.

Answer (score -2):

Yes there is, when do you a dataset you can set it to be retrieved from a query.

for some reason the image is not showingm basically when you configure your dataset in dataset properties, go the query menu on the left, select a datasource, and on the query type choose text and from there you can put any sql you want : for example : 
[image]

Make sure your user has write permission on the database

Comment: Sorry but I just see some blank picture.

Comment: yeah I nocticed, basically what you need to do as explained in my anwser :
 when you configure your dataset in dataset properties, go the query menu on the left, select a datasource, and on the query type choose text and from there you can put any sql you want, for example
`INSERT IN TABLE SEARCHRECORDS(val1,val2,val3)VALUES ( @val1,@val2, @val3)`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But how can I get the input of the user for val1, val2 and val3 IN the report, without using the parameters at the top?

Comment: oh sorry I misread your question, no from what I know what you are trying to do is not possible,

at best what you can do is have a value shown and have buttons to increase or decrease that value but there is nothing to enter text in a report.